# pg_bulkload error: "FATAL: unrecognized configuration parameter "wal_level""

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to give `pg_bulkload` a try.

When I try to use the postgresql executable it provides, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/src/pg_bulkload-3.0.1/bin> ./postgresql start -D /pg_data
server starting
/usr/local/src/pg_bulkload-3.0.1/bin>
FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "wal_level"
```

Google turned up an exact match for this error when someone was using a 9.0 version of psql to run a script on an instance of Postgres 8.4.  I don't see how that could be related to my case--I have two versions of Postgres, but I'm sure I'm pointing at the right directory...  any thoughts are very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the docs, PostgreSQL 9.x supports a configuration parameter named "wal_level", but version 8.4 does not. The postgresql.conf file for my 9.0.something server has that parameter; the one for my 8.4 server does not.

- [PostgreSQL 9.x server configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html)
- [PostgreSQL 8.4 server configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/runtime-config-wal.html)

Your error message suggests you're running version 8.4, but it's reading the configuration file for a 9.x server. Check your postgresql.conf and installation process. I'm thinking pg_bulkload might have "helped" you in ways you didn't anticipate.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right, @Catcall--that was my initial hunch, but I wasn't sure how it was finding a non-9.x executable.  Answer to that was easy enough, my postgresql is pointing to 8.4.4.

There's a -p /path/to/postgresql parameter--I haven't had a chance to try it that way yet, but I will and will report back.  I assume your answer is right though, given the above observation (doh!).  Thanks for helping a Unix/DBA newbie out!

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can be a bit tricky to install pg_bulkload to the right place if you have more than one version of PostgreSQL installed on your machine. My first problem was that pg_bulkload (version 3.1.6) could not find pg_port library. I copied the library libpgport.a (a static library) to /usr/local/lib where it was found, but this approach is not recommended, because this is only a quick fix that doesn't work at the end. So, very soon there was another problem: "undefined reference to `pstrdup'". I reckon that in pg_bulkload there should be a possibility of pointing out where PostgreSQL is installed. Well, I changed Makefile of pg_bulkload in pg_bulkload-3.1.6/bin, namely line with PG_LIBS: **PG_LIBS = $(libpq) -L/*current location of your PostgreSQL*/PostgreSQL/pgsql/lib -lpgport -lpgcommon**. -lpgport has to be added before -lpgcommon. Last but not least, to compile and install pg_bulkload you shoud modify your PATH: **PATH=/*current location of your PostgreSQL*/PostgreSQL/pgsql/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1 [install]**; This makes sure that your pg_bulkload will be added to the correct version of PostgreSQL (in my case 9.3). Enjoy!